# Split a list on spaces and group quoted characters

Tags: java, string, minecraft

I'm trying to parse an input string into tokens, where each token is a word in the string.
However, I also want the tokens to be able to contain spaces, and for clearer syntax, i'd like to be able to have quotes appear half way through a token, and be able to escape quotes (`\"`)

Example input strings and the outputs I'd want (removing quotes from output to denote strings for readability):

- Input: `diamond_sword name:"test name"` -> Output: [diamond_sword, name:test name]
- Input: `stick 1 name:"The \"Holy\" Stick"` -> Output: [stick, 1, name:The "Holy" Stick]

Instead of doing what many others have asked in previous questions, I don't want the quotes to have to be separate from other words (`name:"string"`), and I only want *escaped* quotes to remain, removing all unescaped quotes.

Is this possible? What would it look like to turn a string into a list this way?

Comment: Java has the built-in class [`StreamTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html), which supports the described syntax, albeit it feels somewhat clunky to use, as the syntax rules have to be set up separately for every round of parsing.

Comment: @Izruo How would I use a stream tokenizer to accomplish this? Never heard of them before and I'm not sure where to start

Comment: I did some research: It seems that `StreamTokenizer` [is in the process of being deprecated](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180207). I'd therefore recommend to use a manual approach instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {
    private static List<String> parse(String in) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(in);
        char[] chars = in.toCharArray();
        var words = new ArrayList<String>();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (chars[i] == ' ') {
                // Space; add the current token to the result array.
                words.add(sb.toString());
                sb.setLength(0);
            } else if (chars[i] == '"') {
                // Iterate until the next unescaped quote
                // (Assumes strings are well-formatted; a more robust version
                //  wouldn't and would better handle error cases)
                for (i++; chars[i] != '"'; i++) {
                    // If current character is a backslash, skip and append
                    // the next
                    if (chars[i] == '\\') {
                        i++;
                    }
                    sb.append(chars[i]);
                }
            } else {
                sb.append(chars[i]);
            }
        }
        words.add(sb.toString()); // Don't forget the final token
        return words;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings =
            List.of("diamond_sword name:\"test name\"",
                    "stick 1 name:\"The \\\"Holy\\\" Stick\"");

        for (String s : strings) {
            List<String> words = parse(s);
            System.out.println(words);
        }
    }
}
```

when compiled and run, prints out

```
[diamond_sword, name:test name]
[stick, 1, name:The "Holy" Stick]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!